# Where do I get OpenAM Client SDK

Tags: single-sign-on, opensso, openam

I want to use the OpenAM SDK Client but I can't find it.

[This page](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Deploy+OpenAM+Client+SDK) explains how to deploy the OpenAM Client SDK samples (I'm planning to start there), but it assumes I've already downloaded it.

I can't find it in the [OpenAM](http://openam.forgerock.org/) [download section](http://forgerock.org/openam.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a link to openam_953.zip on that page.  Click on the text that says "OpenAM 9.5.3" (Not the SHA, WAR or TOOLS links)  It sends you to http://download.forgerock.org/downloads/openam/snapshot9.5/openam_953.zip

Comment: Thank you for spoon feeding the link since my answer was apparently not detailed enough.

Answer (score 4):

The [Official OpenAM Website](http://openam.forgerock.org/) has a [Downloads section](http://forgerock.org/openam.html).

Quoting the page you linked to:

> If you have not already done so, download and unzip the openam_953.zip file
>
> The Client SDK and samples are then available in the
> zip-root/openam/samples/openam-client.zip

<sub>(corrected for current version of software, 9.5.3 as opposed to 9.0)</sub>

Comment: I'd already checked there, but I couldn't find the client SDK there. (just updated the question about this)

Comment: There's no openam_953.zip file to download in the OpenAM downloads section. There's an openam_953.war but that's OpenAM, not the client SDK.

Comment: Or I'll just provide you the link, since you're apparently incapable of finding it within 1" of where you found the .war link: http://download.forgerock.org/downloads/openam/snapshot9.5/openam_953.zip I apologize for the tone of this comment, but this site is for **professionals only** and this really isn't even close to complicated.